# Composer autoloading with PSR4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

Probably something trivial but I have a problem with basic autoloading. I wanna create sandbox project just for testing new solutions so I've created following structure:

```
Sandbox
|- index.php
|- composer.json
|- vendor
|  |- {autogenerated content}
|- src
   |- Working.php
```

File `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/sandbox",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "email": "bar@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "dev-master"
    },
    "psr-4": {
        "Sandbox\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Of course I've run `composer.update` after changes. Then I wrote a trivial body of `Working.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Sandbox;

class Working
{
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And of course `index.php` as well:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Sandbox\Working;

new Working();

?>
```

I checked permissions to those files just to be sure but when I try to run I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sandbox\Working' not found in /var/www/Sandbox/index.php on line 6
```

I realize it's probably something trivial but what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your `composer.json` you are missing `autoload` key.
It should be like

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Sandbox\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
"psr-4": {
        "Sandbox\\": "src/"
    }
```

Should be:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Sandbox\\": "src/"
    }
```

So your file would be:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/sandbox",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "email": "bar@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "Sandbox\\": "src/"
        }          
    }
}
```